# Providing an isolation level to "DbConnection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel)" has no effect on the SQL sent to the database

Tags: sql, transactions, isolation-level, executenonquery, dbconnection

I've been doing some testing in the `System.Data` namespace using **SQL Server Profiler**, and noticed that whatever `IsolationLevel` you provide to `DbConnection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel)` doesn't change the SQL that is actually sent to the database. For example, this code:

```
using DbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(EFContext.GetConnectionString());
connection.Open();
using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
//           changing this has no effect on the SQL ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = transaction;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __TEST";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Commit();
```

will always show these same SQL statements in **SQL Server Profiler**:

| EventClass | ApplicationName | TextData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TM: Begin Tran completed | Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider | BEGIN TRANSACTION |
| SQL: BatchCompleted | Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider | DROP TABLE IF EXISTS __TEST |
| TM: Commit Tran completed | Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider | COMMIT TRANSACTION |

So my question is, what is the use of providing an isolation level to `DbConnection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel)` if it does not affect the SQL?

I know that one can manually send a statement like `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`, so why doesn't `BeginTransaction` do this?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/0fb28ba5-ddcb-4d02-95c3-aa5b05ec6092

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Did I read in that link that there is some extra information being sent to the database that is not visible in the SQL text?

Comment: Presumably it's using a special TransMgrReq packet in TDS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/0fb28ba5-ddcb-4d02-95c3-aa5b05ec6092 so the profiler is just showing a rough representation of what's going on, not what actually happens. A similar thing happens if you call a stored procedure with OUTPUT parameters, or if you do a bulk-copy: the profiler just makes stuff up. Note that the Profiler is ancient, you should use an XEvents Session if you want proper tracing.